# Mechanical Soup: Complex logins

Tags: python, mechanicalsoup

I am trying to create a python script with mechanicalsoup to login to verizon.com.
The login page itself loads just fine. The problem I am facing is the response after submitting my login. Verizon has a "please wait" loading screen after submitting credentials. So, when I print out the response to the login attempt, I am not greeted with my user dashboard or 2FA input field. I am instead only seeing the content of the "please wait" page when I print out the response. Is there a workaround for this without using something more robust like selenium?

Code:

```
import mechanicalsoup
import time

browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser()
browser.set_user_agent('Mozilla/5.0')
browser.open("https://secure.verizon.com/vzauth/UI/Login")

browser.select_form('form[action="https://secure.verizon.com/vzauth/UI/Login"]')
browser.form.print_summary()
browser["IDToken1"] = "bobjohnson"
browser["IDToken2"] = "bobjohnson123"
resp = browser.submit_selected()
time.sleep(3)
print(resp.text)
```

Comment: There is definitely heavy use of JavaScript on this page, so my immediate reaction is that you'd have an easier time with something like Selenium. Looking at the HTML, I see the login form is a normal POST with submit input, but there may be some JavaScript manipulation behind the scenes. To get MechanicalSoup to work, you would likely need to reverse engineer the HTTP request that is made when you click the "Sign in" button by inspecting the JavaScript, which may be tedious or even impossible. Sorry I can't be of more help!